# Counting the numbers on the kilometer markers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Along a road, there exists marks for every passed kilometer after every kilometer, at the start where the mark shows 0. A hiker who starts walking at the roads start devote himself to count the numbers on the marks. How many kilometers has the hiker walked/passed at the mark showing the number 2013?

I have the solutions aswell but I don't understand the solution. However I will delay with posting the solution until later, perhaps somebody here can solve it anyway.

Regards!

Comment: Are you saying that after 2 km, the hiker will see 1 and 2?

Comment: You have to decide for yourself. However, my interpretation is; the first sign shows 0km at the start, the second sign shows 1km and the third sign shows 2km etc. But I can't solve the problem so I don't know what to say really. But please, don't take my word for it and go on the wrong path, you really shouldn't think like me right now because I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: @drehman96, your description of the problem doesn't make sense (to me, at least, and I suspect to others as well).  It would help if you did one or more of the following:  1. Give a link to the problem, if it appears online somewhere.  2. Report the problem *exactly* as you found it, taking care to proofread what you've written.  3. Post the solution, which might allow people to work backwards and figure out what the problem is asking for.

Comment: I don't live in an English speaking country and I don't Think that this problem is out there in English, I had to translate it from Another language. And it is weird, I know it is, I can't understand it myself.

Comment: Yeah, this is a weird question. The first part ("... devote himself to count the number on the marks") doesn't seem to related to what the question is asking: How many kilometers has the hiker walked/passed at the mark showing the number 2013? If I were to answer the second question, I would assume that the hiker has walked 2013 km, and has passed 2014 signs.

Comment: This is a question from a Contest, so it's not the usual ones that you would find in a book.

Comment: You have translated it wrong. Perhaps you should post the original? Maybe "the number 2013" should be "the 2013th digit"?

Answer (score 0):

If the hiker sees mile 1, 2, 3, like normal, it is a simple formula - $\frac{x^2+x}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** The single digit numbers add up to $10$ numbers and corresponds to $9$ passed kilometers. The $2$ digit numbers together holds a total of $180$ numbers (I don't get this part). When you pass the sign with the number $99$, which is the biggest two digit number, you have walked a total of $9+90=99$km. All the three digit numbers together contain $3\times 900>2013$ numbers. So, when one have passed the sign with the $2013$ number/digit one have walked at least a $3$ digit number of kilometers. We have the following:
$$2013 = 10 + 180 + 6 · (3 · 100) + 3 · 7 + 2$$ 
Which means that at the sign with the $2013$th digit, one passed 
$9 + 90 + 6 \times 100 + 7 + 1 = 707$ kilometers.

If somebody could explain this I would be greatful.

Answer (score 0):

Each $2$ digit number is composed of $2$ digits, and there are $90$ of them. Therefore there are $2\times90=180$ digits in $2$ digit numbers.
With this you get the answer:$$2013=1(10)+2(90)+3(607)+2$$
$1,2,3$ are the amount of digits in a number.
Thus the total amount of numbers is $$10+90+607=707$$

Comment: Oh damn, so you have to Count the actual digits and no the value of the numbers, damn. Thanks alot man! But one more thing, how do you get the rest two? Could you explain how you turn the +2 into 10+90?

Regards!

Comment: Imagine instead it was asking for the $2011$th digit. $2011=1(10)+2(90)+3(607)$, so it'll be the the first digit of a $3$-digit number. The $2013$th digit will thus be the third digit of the same $3$-digit number. It takes some thinking and I don't know if I explained it very well.

Comment: Btw what contest was this question from?

Comment: It is a contest between the schools in sweden. I have never participated, however I was thinking of doing it this time.